# Flutter parece no hacer llamadas http en produccion pero si en debug

Tags: api, http, flutter, apk, dart

Tengo un problema que no tengo ni idea de por qué puede ocurrir ni de como arreglarlo. Me he roto la cabeza pero no veo solución o estoy demasiado ciego.

Mi problema es el siguiente. He creado una aplicaron móvil con Flutter y en ella se hacen peticiones GET a una API (cualquier API). Todo parece funcionar correctamente en mi emulador de Android Studio con la app en debug. La aplicación es capaz de traer y pintar cualquier dato obtenido del API.

Los problemas llegan cuando genero el APK release en produccion supuestamente y lo instalo en un dispositivo. La aplicación no consigue traer datos. Si hago debug directamente a un terminal móvil con el modo depuración USB activo también funciona perfectamente.

He intentado forzar a que la app compruebe si hay Internet para hacer la llamada pero sigue el mismo problema.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectivity = new Connectivity();
    subscription = connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result){
      _connectionStatus = result.toString();
      print(_connectionStatus);
      if(result == ConnectivityResult.wifi || result == ConnectivityResult.mobile){
        this.getJsonData();
      }
    });

  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Este es un ejemplo de mi llamada por si sirve de algo

```
    Future<bool> getJsonData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        // LLAMADA HTTP GET
        Uri.encodeFull(url), // ENDPOINT
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}); // HEADERS

    print(response.body);

    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body); // CONVERSIÓN
      data = convertDataToJson;
    });

    return true;
  }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y si hace falta algún dato mas, por favor, decidme.

Comment: Puedes probar la app instalando directamente en tu dispositivo android (debug) en lugar del emulador , para ver si funciona  y nos comentas.

Comment: Otra pregunta, como generas el apk que instalas en tu celular?

Comment: para generar el apk utilizo `flutter build apk` y no consigo hacer funcionar el debug en mi móvil por ahora. El apk se instala ok y funcionan menús y demás cosas que no tienen llamadas (Todo lo que se programe desde 0 en la app) pero no trae datos de APIs. Intentaré probar otra vez a ejecutarlo desde el móvil en debug. Gracias

Comment: Con respecto a hacer el run de la app desde Android Studio a un dispositivo móvil... funciona perfectamente. Puedo ver la app en el dispositivo móvil perfectamente con todos sus datos y puedo hacer cambios en el código y se reflejan en la app. Todo correcto. Sigo sin poder traer datos con la app compilada.

Comment: ¿No será que el servidor al que intentas acceder lo tienes ejecutándose en tu ordenador de desarrollo, y la IP en la que escucha es privada? Eso explicaría por qué, si la app está conectada a la misma red que el servidor, funciona, pero tan pronto como la app se ejecuta en otra red (la de telefonía) deja de funcionar.

Comment: No creo que sea el caso. La API es externa, está en azure y funciona con otras aplicaciones que he creado con ionic por ejemplo. Las otras apps funcionan tanto con wifi como con datos móviles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, ya veo por donde puede estar el error, al momento de usar el comando `flutter build apk`,  la build que se genera por default es `release`.

Por lo que cuando se crea un proyecto desde cero en Flutter, te genera varias carpetas para tu proyecto Android dentro de `android/app/src`, entre ellas `main` , `debug` , `profile`.

Si notas el `AndroidManifest.xml` dentro de `debug` y `profile`, ya vienen con el permiso de internet agregado :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Pero si miras el `AndroidManifest.xml` dentro de `main` , no lo trae. Estoy seguro que al compilar la app , hace un merge de los AndroidManifest según cada ambiente, pero como no encuentra el de `release`, solo toma el manifest por default de main (sin permisos de Internet).

Así que prueba agregando ese permiso en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de main.

Comment: Perfecto @diegoveloper muchísimas gracias. Esto funcionó a la perfección para mí. Ahora siempre lo tendré en cuenta para que no me vuelva a pasar ;)