# Flutter (PageView) a veces no carga ningún hijo (children)

Tags: flutter

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación básica que tiene pageView con 3 hijos.
Se me ha presentado el problema de que a veces no carga el PageView, pero en tiempo de depuración nunca veo el problema.
El problema se me presenta cuando hago "Flutter build apk" y "Flutter install".
Muchas de las veces carga normal,
pero hay veces que solo carga AppBar, y nada mas, el PageView no carga.

Aquí les muestro el código que hice a modo de ejemplo, porque pensaba que en mi aplicación estaba algo mal, y llegué a algo básico.
Aclaración: el problema se presenta a veces cuando finalizo la app, cuando la app se mantiene en memoria, va todo bien.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Main',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: const TabsPage(),
      routes: {
        '/search': (_) => const SearchPage(),
        '/listadoPmis': (_) => const ListadoPmisPage(),
        '/listadoSubestaciones': (_) => const ListadoSubestacionesPage(),
        '/listadoPfs': (_) => const ListadoPfsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Y ahora el TabsPage

```
class TabsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Firu"), actions: const [
        _IconButton(),
      ]),
      body: const _Pages(),
      bottomNavigationBar: const Navegacion(),
    );
  }
}


class _Pages extends StatefulWidget {
  const _Pages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_Pages> createState() => _PagesState();
}

class _PagesState extends State<_Pages> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      children: const [
        Text(
          'Incio',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),
        ),
        Text(
          'medio',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),
        ),
        Text(
          'último',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _Paginas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<_Paginas> createState() => _PaginasState();
}

class _PaginasState extends State<_Paginas> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<AppStorage>(context, listen: false).readLocalData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text('hola mndo');
    /*
    // final pageController = Provider.of<NavegacionModel>(context);
    return PageView(
        // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        // controller: pageController.pageController,
        children: const [
          Text('Inicio Page 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26)),
          Text('Listado Page 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26)),
          Text('Creditos Page 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26))
        ]);
    // children: const [InicioPage(), ListadosPage(), CreditosPage()]);

    */
  }
}
```

Aqui muestro la Pantalla con funcionamiento normal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora muestro despues de finalizar y abrir la app varias veces, falla y no responde PageView. Esta vacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceré alguién me pueda iluminar por favor

Comment: declaraste los permisos de internet en modo release? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276437/flutter-parece-no-hacer-llamadas-http-en-produccion-pero-si-en-debug

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, la app no necesita internet, todo es offline. Pero de todas maneras he seguido los pasos del link que pusiste. Agregar permisos de internet en en el AndroidManifest.xml que esta dentro del main.

El problema sigue, 
Yo uso esta configuración
       Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
       Framework • revision fb57da5f94 (hace 11 días) • 2022-05-19 15:50:29 
       -0700
       Engine • revision caaafc5604
       Tools • Dart 2.17.1 • DevTools 2.12.2
He llegado a pensar que es un bug porque he creado un ejemplo básico para esto

Comment: falla siempre o a veces? solo pasa cuando generas el apk? que hay en el metodo readLocalData ? el código que agregaste está comentado, lo hiciste a propósito?

Comment: Si comenté a propósito porque pensé que era el problema pero igual falla.

Comment: falla siempre o a veces? solo pasa cuando generas el apk? que hay en el metodo readLocalData ?

Comment: En widget TabsPage dentro de body Scafold body: const _Pages(),
El widget _Pages no solo tiene el widget con tres hijos nada mas, El resto donde esta readLocalData, para el ejemplo no se esta usando.

El problema en modo de depuración nunca pasa,
El problema se presenta a veces haciendo "flutter build apk" & "flutter install"
Cuando cierro completamente la app, hay veces que falla aleatoriamente.
Gracias por tu tiempo @diegoveloper

Comment: es raro lo q mencionas, sería ideal q agregas más info, algún video para ver el problema, o más código también, que es ? controller: pageController.pageController,

Comment: Si es raro, ya hice video con el problema.
La aplicación la he subido al playstore, Te paso el link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firu.firu_reader

o si no te envio el apk.

el link de la app
https://github.com/yuber83/firu_reader/tree/master

Soy nuevo y no se como hacerte llegar estos datos, por si estan incorrectamente enviados. Recuerda por favor que he creado el widget _Pages pero no esta en el repo porque fueron modificaciones para ver el problema. Aqui el video https://www.mediafire.com/file/sx2kk36ckvryk5i/WhatsApp+Video+2022-06-01+at+9.21.47+PM.mp4/file

Comment: En el video se observa que el pageview nunca carga, pero ha veces si carga normal. Repito en modo debug siempre funciona bien por eso no me di cuenta del problema muy tarde.

Comment: Paso el link de video en otra plataforma,
https://gfycat.com/brokenevilfinnishspitz

Comment: El link del código que pusiste no se puede ver

Comment: ok, disculpa, no se como hacer para mostrarte, lo pongo en media fire.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/wmr3q9mlpgnntk7/firu_reader-main.zip/file

Recuerda por favor que en el ejemplo que pusé en este post he creado el widget _Paginas() para probar y seguia ocurriendo el problema.
PD: Estoy empezando en flutter. Gracias @diegoveloper