# Problemas con PageView y Null Check Operator

Tags: flutter

tengo un problema al realizar un PageView. En modo debug me aparece todo perfecto pero al usar el flutter run --release me marca esta anotación:

```
h List all available interactive commands.       
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
I/flutter (21856): Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (21856): #0      _PagePosition.applyViewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:455)
I/flutter (21856): #1      RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1456)      
I/flutter (21856): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #18     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545)
I/flutter (21856): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #22     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171)    
I/flutter (21856): #23     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1003)
I/flutter (21856): #24     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240)
I/flutter (21856): #25     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403)
I/flutter (21856): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #30     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376)
I/flutter (21856): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #40     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #65     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3462)
I/flutter (21856): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #69     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:749)
I/flutter (21856): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #82     RenderObject.layout 
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116)
I/flutter (21856): #84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915)
I/flutter (21856): #85     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165)
I/flutter (21856): #86     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1757)
I/flutter (21856): #87     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887)
I/flutter (21856): #88     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:504)
I/flutter (21856): #89     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:892)
I/flutter (21856): #90     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370)I/flutter (21856): #91     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146)        
I/flutter (21856): #92     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083)
I/flutter (21856): #93     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997)
I/flutter (21856): #97     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151)
I/flutter (21856): #98     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308)
I/flutter (21856): #99     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115)
I/flutter (21856): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

Realmente hasta el momento no he usado ningún operador en null y haciendo la búsqueda en VSCODE no me marca ningún archivo de dart con ese operador.

*Mi código es este:*

**Pantalla Principal**

```
//Flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
// Packages
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
// Owned
import '../providers/providers.dart';
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'screens.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Variables
    const String url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605740345377-554ad040af7f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80';
    final indexProvider = Provider.of<DropdownMenuProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          indexProvider.appBarTitle,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontSize: 22,
            color: const Color(0xFF00ADB5),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        actions: const [
          // Widget: User Image
          AvatarImage(imageURL: url),
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: indexProvider.controller,
        children: const <Widget>[
          HomeScreen(),
          ActivitiesScreen(),
          BudgetScreen(),
          DocumentsScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MenuBar(indexProvider: indexProvider),
    );
  }
}
```

**Provider**

```
//Flutter
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class DropdownMenuProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  // Attributes
  int _indexPage = 0;
  final PageController _controller = PageController();
  String _appBarTitle = 'Hola, Erika';

  // Function: Get -> _indexPage.
  int get indexPage => _indexPage;

  // Function: Set -> _indexPage.
  set indexPage(int indexPage) {
    _indexPage = indexPage;
    _controller.animateToPage(
      indexPage,
      curve: Curves.linear,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
    switch (indexPage) {
      case 1:
        _appBarTitle = 'Actividades';
        break;
      case 2:
        _appBarTitle = 'Cartera';
        break;
      case 3:
        _appBarTitle = 'Documentos';
        break;
      default:
        _appBarTitle = 'Hola, Erika';
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // Function: Get -> _controller.
  PageController get controller => _controller;

  // Function: Get -> _appBarTitle.
  String get appBarTitle => _appBarTitle;

  // Function: Set -> _appBarTitle.
  set appBarTitle(String appBarTitle) {
    _appBarTitle = appBarTitle;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Hasta el momento he revisado si es algún detalle de tener el pageview vacío pero no estoy seguro si es el problema ya que en debug tampoco debería de funcionar pero las physics de material me hacen sospechar de que se es un problema de este tipo ya que al cambiar el pageview se hace la animación como si no hubiera nada en el scroll.

Aquí se puede ver las pantallas en debug y release respectivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que error visual te muestra en release? en debug no ves ningún error en pantalla?

Comment: En pantalla simplemente no muestra lo que aparecería dentro del pageview, sólo pude visualizar el error en la terminal, voy a agregar las pantallas, un momento

Comment: de casualidad no será este problema?  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276437/flutter-parece-no-hacer-llamadas-http-en-produccion-pero-si-en-debug/276703#276703

Comment: No, eso también lo pensé pero al revisar el AndroidManifest si tiene los permisos, de hecho la imagen del appbar usa una petición HTTP.