# Flutter no funcionan los GET de HTTP en apk-release pero si lo hace en el debuggeo

Tags: android, flutter, http-get

Hola programadores de Flutter y Android, ¿Cómo están?

Estoy desarrollando una app que hace un pedido mediante el protocolo HTTP para descargar un archivo .json, luego lo leo y armo una lista de opciones según las opciones disponibles en ese archivo.

Al momento de debuggear la aplicación con el hot reload de Flutter la aplicación funciona fenomenal, el pedido GET mediante HTTP funciona perfecto, y la lista de opciones se genera perfectamente. Estoy debuggeando en un dispositivo físico Android versión 11, también lo probé en un dispositivo físico con Android versión 12.

Luego, y he aquí el problema, cuando genero mi apk con el comando

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Y la instalo en el mismo dispositivo en el cual debuggee anteriormente, la aplicación ya no funciona y queda en la pantalla de carga.

Algunas soluciones que ya intente fueron:

1- Permisos de AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

2- Cambiar de paquete para hacer los pedidos HTTP:
Anteriormente, venía usando el paquete de Flutter

> http.dart

encontré como sugerencia que, en cambio, usara

> dio.dart

3- En vez de instalar en mi dispositivo el archivo

> apk-release.apk

Intente instalar el otro output

> apk-debug.apk

El problema, sigue...

Pero el problema persiste.

Les dejo partes del código que se ejecutan en este momento donde la aplicación hace el GET:

```
void getSongs() async {
    try {
      final dio = Dio();
      final response = await dio
          .get('https://joacoo.pythonanywhere.com/static/json/songs.json');


      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> jsonResponse = response.data;


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
          Song newSong = Song.fromjson(json: jsonResponse[i], id: i);
          songs.add(newSong);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
          String id = songs[i].id.toString();
          String name = songs[i].name;


          songsIDName.add('$id $name');
        }


        songsLoaded = true;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load songs');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      songsLoaded = true;
    }
  }
```

Luego la función *Song.fromjson(json, id)* es un factory de la clase Song:

```
factory Song.fromjson({required dynamic json, required int id}) {
    String nameFromJson = removeASCIIChars(str: json['name'].toString());
    String categoryFromJson =
        removeASCIIChars(str: json['category'].toString());


    return Song(
      name: nameFromJson,
      category: categoryFromJson,
      bpm: json['bpm'],
      tab: json['tab'],
      id: id,
    );
  }
```

Y por último, la función llamada *removeASCIIChars* es para manejar el tema de las ñ.

Pero vuelvo a aclarar, todos estos métodos funcionan a la perfección en el debug, pero no en el release.

¿Alguno sabe por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Hola,  te aseguraste de agregar el permiso de internet en el archivo manifest de la carpeta main `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` ? de ser asi quizas estas teniendo un error al hacer la peticion para poder ver ese tipo de error puedes correr tu app con el comando `flutter run --release`  asi te mandara un log el cual puede indicarte con mayor detalle que error estas teniendo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Flutter parece no hacer llamadas http en produccion pero si en debug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276437/flutter-parece-no-hacer-llamadas-http-en-produccion-pero-si-en-debug)

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que se encuentra en `/release` el permiso para uso de internet :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

ya que en `/release`, de forma predeterminada no viene el permiso.

De hecho esto se especifica en la documentacion:

[Revisar el manifiesto de la aplicación](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest)

> Agregue el permiso
> android.permission.INTERNET si el código de su aplicación necesita
> acceso a Internet. La plantilla estándar no incluye esta etiqueta,
> pero permite el acceso a Internet durante el desarrollo para habilitar
> la comunicación entre las herramientas de Flutter y una aplicación en
> ejecución.